# XSL Transform help needed

Tags: xml, xslt

I have scoured the internet and have not been able to figure out how to do this.
Essentially, I need to rename the root element, and wrap all of the nodes in some tags.
Please see below.
Thank you for your help!

### Actual Xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RefundInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <header>
        <cell>TBD</cell>
        <client>TBD</client>
        <notification_address>TBD</notification_address>
        <password>TBD</password>
        <source>TBD</source>
        <target>TBD</target>
        <version>TBD</version>
      </header>
      <ImageHost>NotImplemented</ImageHost>
      <OriginalOrder>
        <AmountCharged>26.5000</AmountCharged>
        <AmountChargedLessFees>24.0000</AmountChargedLessFees>
        <Fees>0</Fees>
        <Movie>
          <ShowTime>2012-05-05T15:45:00</ShowTime>
          <Title>Marvel's The Avengers 3D</Title>
        </Movie>
        <Theater>
          <Name>Regal Arroyo Grande Stadium 10</Name>
        </Theater>
        <Tickets>
          <Ticket>
            <Description>3D Matinee</Description>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          </Ticket>
          <Ticket>
            <Description>3D Child</Description>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          </Ticket>
        </Tickets>
        <Total>0</Total>
        <TransactionID></TransactionID>
      </OriginalOrder>
      <RefundOrder>
        <PaymentInstruments>
          <PaymentInstrument>
            <ItemType>Credit Card</ItemType>
            <ItemCode />
            <Amount>-1.5000</Amount>
          </PaymentInstrument>
          <PaymentInstrument>
            <ItemType>Promotion Codes</ItemType>
            <ItemCode />
            <Amount>-25.0000</Amount>
          </PaymentInstrument>
        </PaymentInstruments>
        <TransactionID></TransactionID>
      </RefundOrder>
    </RefundInfo>
```

### Required Xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <header>
        <cell>TBD</cell>
        <client>TBD</client>
        <notification_address>TBD</notification_address>
        <password>TBD</password>
        <source>TBD</source>
        <target>TBD</target>
        <version>TBD</version>
      </header>
      <data>
        <row>
          <ImageHost>NotImplemented</ImageHost>
          <OriginalOrder>
            <AmountCharged>26.5000</AmountCharged>
            <AmountChargedLessFees>24.0000</AmountChargedLessFees>
            <Fees>0</Fees>
            <Movie>
              <ShowTime>2012-05-05T15:45:00</ShowTime>
              <Title>Marvel's The Avengers 3D</Title>
            </Movie>
            <Theater>
              <Name>Regal Arroyo Grande Stadium 10</Name>
            </Theater>
            <Tickets>
              <Ticket>
                <Description>3D Matinee</Description>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
              </Ticket>
              <Ticket>
                <Description>3D Child</Description>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
              </Ticket>
            </Tickets>
            <Total>0</Total>
            <TransactionID></TransactionID>
          </OriginalOrder>
          <RefundOrder>
            <PaymentInstruments>
              <PaymentInstrument>
                <ItemType>Credit Card</ItemType>
                <ItemCode />
                <Amount>-1.5000</Amount>
              </PaymentInstrument>
              <PaymentInstrument>
                <ItemType>Promotion Codes</ItemType>
                <ItemCode />
                <Amount>-25.0000</Amount>
              </PaymentInstrument>
            </PaymentInstruments>
            <TransactionID></TransactionID>
          </RefundOrder>
        </row>
      </data>
    </request>
```

### What I have so far, it works, but I know this is the wrong way of doing this

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

      <!--Remove empty lines-->
      <xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>

      <!--Remove Empty Nodes-->
      <xsl:template match="*[not(child::node())]"/>

      <!--Get All Summary Fields-->
      <xsl:variable name="dataRow" select="//OriginalOrder|//RefundOrder|//ImageHost" />

      <xsl:template match="/">
        <request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
          <xsl:copy-of select="//header"/>
          <data>
            <row>
              <xsl:for-each select="$dataRow">
                <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </row>
          </data>
        </request>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: First rule of XSLT: "Never use for-each" (:...
XSLT is functional, so you should prefer using "apply-templates" over for-each etc.

Comment: @hradecek Did you make up this rule? for-each uses a pull approach as apply-templates is a push approach. Both are acceptable.

Comment: While I agree, it is slightly more intense to use for-each, I would like for you to help me solve the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 approaches here. You can pull nodes with `for-each`, push approach with `apply-templates` or a combination of both. There are many ways to do what you want. Here is one example of a combined approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <!--Remove empty lines-->
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!--Remove Empty Nodes-->
    <xsl:template match="*[not(child::node())]"/>
    <!--Get All Summary Fields-->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <request>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/RefundInfo/header"/>
            <data>
                <row>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//OriginalOrder|//RefundOrder|//ImageHost">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </row>
            </data>
        </request>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is complete push approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <!--Remove empty lines-->
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!--Remove Empty Nodes-->
    <xsl:template match="*[not(child::node())]"/>
    <!--Get All Summary Fields-->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <request>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/RefundInfo/header"/>
            <data>
                <row>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//OriginalOrder|//RefundOrder|//ImageHost"/>
                </row>
            </data>
        </request>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Your way works, but its not very pretty. For one, you create a variable called `dataRow` which is not needed to hold the xpath value. You can just call the xpath as `//OriginalOrder|//RefundOrder|//ImageHost`.

Using `//` followed by the node name selects all the nodes with that name no matter where they are in your xml. If this is not is an issue, then its fine, but could be an issue.

Comment: Thank you Phil for answering, however the xmlns(xsi|xsd) values are not in the correct place, rather than being at the root (request) level, they are at header, originalorder and refundorder levels.

Comment: Also, I really do not need specific nodes, I just need only the header node to go out of sequence. Do you think there is a way to do this without the select="//OriginalOrder|//RefundOrder|//ImageHost"?

Comment: @EdwardMMeshuris - as for your first comment, you can add the namespaces where you want. For your 2nd comment; just use `<xsl:apply-templates/>`

Comment: The xsi|xsd is repeated three times, its not at the root level.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by repeated. These namespaces are for schemas and are not relevant or used in your input document